# What is the actual Mechanism of Boosting for building the Models?

Tags: classification, boosting, ensemble-learning

I couldn't able to find the proper step by step procedure to understand the Boosting Mechanism, how does it build the models and the data used to build it. So, I have gone through tutorials which led to the confusions in Boosting Mechanisms, here's the link of the videos which are on youtube, (video clips of hardly 2 minutes each with the mentioned time, although I am writing the things what I is explained in the video.)
[Tutorial1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-S9Hojj1as)[4:56 - 6:00]
[Tutorial2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIPkK5ZAsms)[7:51 - 8:51]

So, heres the thing what is explained in these two tutorials:
[image]

First step is same in both tutorials so everything is fine but from step 2 the things are totally different.

[image]

[image]

Could  someone share the document/blog what is the actual mechanism of boosting, at present I only want to understand the things in simple manner not to deep dive in mathematical knowledge and types of boosting alogorithms like Ada Boost, XGBoost etc. So pls try to keep things simple.

Comment: Have you considered well known introductory textbooks with chapters on the subject? I do think that as far as possible, it’s best to consult original sources such as the original papers. Given that you’ve said that’s not what you are looking for, introductory textbooks would be the next thing. I’m more wary of blog posts because in my experience the number of low quality expository blog posts, particularly in machine learning, far outweighs the number of high quality ones.

Comment: @microhaus  I am following the Book- Hands on Machine Learning with SciKit-Learn. And in that only diagram is mentioned for boosting and later on expalnations on types of boosting and how to implement them. I searched a lot to understand the things , but couldn’t find the luck. So thats why I asked. It would be helpful if you suggest some references regarding what I am actually trying to understand.